# ggplot color bar for less than and great than Average

Tags: r, ggplot2

What I am trying to write is, if the Team on the `X axis` is less than `Average` on the `X axis` or in this case 17.62, color it different and same for Greater than. So `Average` on the `X axis` is black and then the ones above and below are different colors.

```
dput()Road.Team Goalie.Pts.at.Home.Vs.Road.TEAM
1        ANA                        16.67692
2        ARI                        23.20000
3        BOS                        18.86667
4        BUF                        23.14667
5        CAR                        23.44615
6        CBJ                        16.62857
7        CGY                        17.33333
8        CHI                        21.77143
9        COL                        18.70769
10       DAL                        18.70000
11       DET                        20.32000
12       EDM                        16.94118
13       FLA                        23.68000
14       LAK                        12.14118
15       MIN                        17.49333
16       MTL                        21.71429
17       NJD                        11.64444
18       NSH                        17.12000
19       NYI                        15.55556
20       NYR                        18.04444
21       OTT                        13.31429
22       PHI                        21.25714
23       PIT                        20.28235
24       SJS                        14.45714
25       STL                        15.80000
26       TBL                        12.21333
27       TOR                        10.44444
28       VAN                        14.40000
29       VGK                        16.35000
30       WPG                        19.41333
31       WSH                        15.26154
32   Average                        17.62340
```

[image]

```
rm(stats)
stats <- read.csv("HomeGoaliesPtsforVisitingTeam.csv")
stats
library(tidyverse)
p <- stats %>%
  gather(key, value, -Road.Team) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Road.Team, y=value)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
p + labs(y = "FanDuel Goalie Pts",x = "Road Team",title = "Points for Home Goalies Vs Road Team")
```

Comment: Please `dput` some data from your example. In your data you should generate a variable which represent the color, then `aes(x, y, color)`.

Comment: There is the data i am using. I would like to say anything above "Average" be this color and anything below be a different

Answer (score 1):

Create a logical variable in your `stats` data frame and pass that to the `fill` argument in `aes()`.  Something like:

```
stats$compare <- stats$y <= mean(stats$y)

p <- stats %>%
  gather(key, value, -Road.Team) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Road.Team, y=value, fill=compare)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Comment: I added in the df in the edit above. i tried out what you had but couldn't get it to work. `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, compare, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 32
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(stats$y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`